# How to check for both null and undefined in js?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to check for both null and undefined in javascript?

```
if(_var == null || _var == undefined) {

}
```

Comment: I would switch both expressions, but it should work.

Comment: If `_var` is `undefined`, the `_var == undefined` expression will never be reached, because `_var == null` does type coercion, [as Pim noted below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860058/how-to-check-for-both-null-and-undefined-in-js/2860063#2860063) and `undefined == null` returns `true`. The `_var == null` will also be testing for `undefined`, however I believe relying on type coercion is not generally recommended.

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript (pre [ECMAScript 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_5#ECMAScript.2C_5th_Edition)), `undefined` is not a constant, but a global variable, and therefore it is possible to change its value. Therefore it would be more reliable to use the `typeof` operator to check for `undefined`:

```
if (typeof _var === 'undefined') { }
```

In addition your expression would return a ReferenceError if the variable `_var` is not declared. However you would still be able to test it with the `typeof` operator as shown above.

Therefore, you may prefer to use the following:

```
if (typeof _var === 'undefined' || _var === null) { }
```

Comment: Your first case is a little risky since _var might be set to some other falsy value than null.

Comment: @snowlord: True. I removed that part.

Comment: fortunately now on ECMAScript 5, `undefined` is a property of the global object which is non-writable, non-configurable (non-deletable) and non-enumerable  :)

Answer (score 4):

yes

However using the == operator it is not necesary. using foo == null will also be true of foo is undefined. Note however that undefined and null or not(!) the same. It is because that == does type coersion that foo == null is also true for foo is undefined.

Comment: +1, this is the shortest way to achieve it, and it is completely described in the spec: [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3) (no worries about type coercion)... `if (_var == null) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!_var) {
    // Code here.
}
```

This should work since both `undefined` and `null` are type coerced to `false`.

Of course there is the small problem if `_var` is actually `false` but it works since in most cases you would want to know if `_var` is not `true` and not an object.

Comment: Note that there are three other falsy values in JavaScript apart from `false`, `null` and `undefined`: An empty string `""`, `0`, and `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `$defined` function in mootools (and there must be an equivalent in jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
var valuea: number;
var valueb: number = null;

function check(x, name) {
    if (x == null) {
        console.log(name + ' == null');
    }

    if (x === null) {
        console.log(name + ' === null');
    }

    if (typeof x === 'undefined') {
        console.log(name + ' is undefined');
    }
}

check(a, 'a');
check(b, 'b');
```